# Change the type of the key in a dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary

I got this JSON:

```
{
  "test":{
    "0":{
      "test":"test"
    }
  }
}
```

The key in a JSON can only be a string, so when I retrieve this json, I got the following declaration:

```
let myJson = [String: [String: Any]]()
```

Now I want to filter out all the keys than can be casted to an integer, so the dictionary I want to use is:

```
let myJson2 = [Int: [String: Any]]()
```

How can I `compactMap`/`filter` `myJson` to `myJson2` to filter out all the `Int` keys and copy the value? I got this:

```
var myJson2 = [Int: [String: Any]]()

for (key, value) in myJson {
    guard let keyInt = Int(key) else { return }
    myJson2[keyInt] = value
}
```

But I am looking for a solution with compactMap which can do it in 1 line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `compactMap` on the sequence of key/value pairs of the original
dictionary to extract those with an integer key, and `Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues:)` to create a new dictionary:

```
let myDict: [String: [String: Any]] = [
    "test": [ "0": [ "test" : "test" ]],
    "123": [ "1" :[ "foo": "bar" ] ]
]

let myDict2 = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: myDict.compactMap { (key, value) in
    Int(key).map { ($0, value) }
})

print(myDict2) // [123: ["1": ["foo": "bar"]]]
print(type(of: myDict2)) // Dictionary<Int, Dictionary<String, Any>>
```

Here it is assumed that all strings represent *different* integers. If that
is not guaranteed then use

```
let myDict2 = Dictionary(myDict.compactMap { (key, value) in
    Int(key).map { ($0, value) }
}, uniquingKeysWith: { $1 })
```

instead. The additional parameter determines which value
is used in the case of duplicate keys,  with `{ $1 }` the last one
“wins”.